# How to redirect my child process stdout to my main program jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook, stdout

I'm learning python on jupyter notebook, on windows. For one of my project, I need multiprocessing. My problem is that my child process prints and displays errors in the command window and I would like for it to display them in my jupyter notebook.

I tried getting the sys.stdout of the main program and giving it to the child process through a Pipe but when trying to send it, I get this error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x04A1AA98>: attribute lookup <lambda> on jupyter_client.session failed
```

I figure that the Pipe doesn't like the type of object sys.stdout gives so I tried converting it to a string but I didn't manage to unstring it afterwards in the child process (eval does not work).

Main file :

```py
def safefunc(function,play,pause,stop): # arg of type <enum 'Key'>
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    parent_conn2, child_conn2 = Pipe()
    original = sys.stdout
    parent_conn2.send(original)
    processfailsafe = multiprocessing.Process(target = mybunchoffunc.failsafefunc, args = (play,pause,stop,child_conn))
    processfunction = multiprocessing.Process(target = mybunchoffunc.funcfunc, args = (function,parent_conn,child_conn2))
    processfailsafe.start()
    processfunction.start()
    processfunction.join()
```

mybunchoffunc.py file :

```py
def funcfunc(function,conn,conn2):
    current_process_pid = psutil.Process().pid
    conn.send(current_process_pid)
    orig = conn2.recv()
    sys.stdout = orig
    function()
    failpid = conn.recv()
    failproc = psutil.Process(failpid)
    failproc.terminate()
```

The rest of my program works perfectly (if you want the background, my goal is to have a function that takes a function adn 3 pynput keys as arguments, runs the function in one process and a pynput listener one another process and have the 3 keys be able to resume, pause and stop the process with the function).
This is just a quality of life improvement to my program but I feel like learning how to manage processes output is an important thing to learn.